# Do animate when every time props.children is changed in styled-components using hooks

Tags: reactjs, animation, styled-components

I want to trigger my animation in hooks component named Counter with styled-components v4 when every time props.children is changed but I don't know how to implement my code.

here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled, { css, keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const highlight = keyframes`
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
`;

const highlightAnimation = css`
  animation: ${highlight} 1s ease;
`;

const Circle = styled.div`
  // ...other attributes
  ${highlightAnimation}
`;

const Counter = ({ children, color, status }) => {
  return (
    <Circle color={color} status={status}>
      {children}
    </Circle>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Animates only once when first rendered.

I think it's a problem with render like diffing algorithm in virtualDOM.

It doesn't re-render when just children changes. It just changes the text not re-render

Comment: I don't see you use state in any of your components (you are importing it but never use it). you could combine useState with useEffect. UseEffect will be called whenever something changes: `useEffect(()=>setSomeStateBecauseSomethingChanged(),[valueChanged])`

Comment: @HMR
Thanks for reply. You're right I'd never used useState.
Using useEffect, I can catch the moment every time children is changed but I don't know how to **trigger** that animation

Comment: Just add this in Counter component before return - `useEffect(()=>{console.log("Children changed")},[children])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trigger a rerender, therefore a new animation will apply, you just need to add a `key`  to your component with the value you want the component to rerender with on change.

```
 <Circle color={color} status={status} key={`${color}-${status}`}>
```

have a look at how React work in terms of reconciliation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: wow. you're right. I already knew reconciliation but I didn't come up with using `key`.  Thanks.